# Xamarin C# - Rooted Android Write file in /data/data folder

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i want to modify data in /data/data or /system
lets call it file.bin

```
var sdcardPath = Android.OS.Environment.RootDirectory.Path;
var files = Path.Combine(sdcardPath, "/data/data/com.xyz/file.bin");
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("chmod 777" + files);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(files));
```

i can read  that file, but cant read because System.UnauthorizedAccessException
i think it must have permission in manifest like SDCard write permission, but i cant find any documentation to get /Data Write.

im trying with mounting data to readWrite but still cant grant write access

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su " + "mount -o rw, remount, rw /data ");
```

anyone can Help me pls.

Comment: Do you have write access to the file? Check the file permissions, but I would assuming you are going to have to `chmod` those files.

Comment: already check file permisson. i just want to make that file can be writable. i can write if i put the file to sdcard